# Regex help needed: Match only second subfolder in URL

Tags: google-analytics

I want to fire a Tag in GTM only upon the category. The URL structure is as follows.

Product page:  www.domain.com/all-products/category-1/product-2
Category page: www.domain.com/all-products/category-1/

How can I only match it someone visits to the category pages?

I tried `^\/products-page\/.*\/$` but that also returns any product pages.

Answer (score 0):

Julian, I would take a different approach - use Custom JavaScript macro to return the number of "subfolders" and based on what it returns, either fire you desired tag or don't.

The code for returning the number of subfolder (used in custom JS macro) is this:

```
function() {
    var urlFolders = document.location.pathname.split("/").length;
    return urlFolders -1 ;
}
```

So if you want to **track all the category pages, based on your questions I suggest you fire this tag when the macro returns value of 2**. I am subtracting -1 in the macro *return* statement as **Analytics** by default track only *document.path* (not the whole URL).

Hope this makes sense :)